# Maximal "distance" of two probability measures?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the two coins (i.e., probability measures on the discrete set ${0,1}$) $C_{0.9}$ and $C_{0.99}$, where $C_{x}$ is the coin having probability of turning head equal to $x$.

Let $\mu_{0.9}$ and $\mu_{0.99}$ be the probability measures on $2^{\omega}$ (Markov chains) obtained by flipping infinitely often the two coin $C_{0.9}$ and $C_{0.99}$ respectively. So that, for instance, the probability assigned by $\mu_{0.9}$ to the (open) set of sequences starting with two zeros is $0.81$.

**Question:** I would like to calculate $D(\mu_{0.9}, \mu_{0.99})$ defined as:

$D(\mu_{0.9}, \mu_{0.99})$ = $\displaystyle \bigsqcup_{B} \{ |\mu_{0.9}(B) - \mu_{0.99}(B)| \ \ $ ;  $B$ a Borel subset of $2^{\omega}  \}$.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I have the feeling that the above supremum should be strictly less than $1$ and that the maximizing event should be the set of sequences starting with about 25 ones. The number 25 comes from the function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)= {0.99}^x - {0.9}^x$ which attains its maximum around 25.

**Question 2:** More generally, is the function $D$ (mapping pairs of probability measures to the unit interval) as defined above well known?

Thank you in advance for any comment!

Comment: Regarding Question 2: [Total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures).

Comment: @martini: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Call $B$ the event that the asymptotic proportion of heads exists and is 0.9, then the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) shows that $\mu_{0.9}(B)=1$ and $\mu_{0.99}(B)=0$. Hence $D(\mu_{0.9},\mu_{0.99})=1$. One sees that in fact the measures $\mu_{0.9}$ and $\mu_{0.99}$ are [mutually singular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_measure).